# Interpretation of interaction plot from GLM

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, interaction, interpretation

I'm doing a moderation analysis in R. My dependent variable is a rate (Diffcount/totalcount), the independent variable is an index (continuous), and the moderator is a categorical variable (3 levels). I fitted a negative binomial regression model using `glm.nb` from `MASS`, and I used offset term like below:

```
glm.nb(Diffcount~Index1*factor3 + offset(log(totalcount)), data = dt)
```

I generated a interaction plot for this model, using `interact_plot` from `interactions` package.[image]
What I'm really confusing about is the interpretation of the y-axis. Does the value represent the rate (i.e., Diffcount/totalcount), a probability, or maybe something else? Thank you!

Comment: What is `totalcount`?  Is there a fixed possible total number that `Diffcount` can take, like a maximum number of heads out of a known number of coin tosses?

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica Yes there is a fixed possible number. Basically I'm calculating the count of decayed teeth in a person's mouth at two different time point. So `totalcount` refers to how many healthy teeth we found on this person at time1, and `Diffcount` refers to the increasement of decayed teeth from time1 to time2.

Comment: It would also be useful to see your model output using summary() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The y axis is the conditional expectation.  It is interpreted depending on what you pass as covariates to the predict method for `glm.nb`.  Let's see a small example.

I'm going to simulate data from

$$\log(E[y\mid x]) = -2 + 0.8x + 0.2z -0.3xz + \log(n) $$

for binary $z$, which is similar to your model.  I will simulate the data to be from a poisson distribution despite us using the engative binomial.

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- seq(-2, 2, 0.1)
z <- letters[1:2]

dgrid <- crossing(x, z)
dgrid$n <- rpois(nrow(dgrid), 10)

X <- model.matrix(~x*z, data=dgrid)
eta <- X %*% c(-2, 0.8, 0.2, -0.3) + log(dgrid$n)
dgrid$y <- rpois(nrow(dgrid), exp(eta))
```

Let's now plot our predictions.  To do so, we need to specify values of $x$, $z$, and $n$.  Let's set $z=a$ and then compute the prediction over a grid of $x$ values for 2 values of $n$ (2 and 10).  Plot is shown below

```
fit <- MASS::glm.nb(y~x*z + offset(log(n)), data=dgrid)
dpred <- crossing(x, z='a', n=c(2, 10))
dpred$mu <- predict(fit, newdata=dpred, type='response')

dpred %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, mu, color=factor(n))) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Two different curves.  The curve depends on what the value of $n$ is -- generally, larger $n$ means larger values of the prediction.

Now, onto your questions.

### What I'm really confusing about is the interpretation of the y-axis.

The y axis here and in your plot is the expected value for the outcome.  It isn't a rate *per se*, it is an expected count variable.  Why should prediction be a floating point number and not an integer when the outcome is an integer?  It is the *expected* count, and it is more than reasonable to talk about the expected outcome being a float.

To get the expected rate, set $n=1$ when making the prediction call, as follows

```
dpred <- crossing(x, z='a', n=1)
dpred$mu <- predict(fit, newdata=dpred, type='response')
```

I imagine the library you've used to construct that plot might be setting $n=1$, but I can't be sure.  If you can, verify this is actually the case before proceeding.  Else, you can use a different library which makes this more transparent, like `{marginaleffects}`.  Here is how I would make your plot in that library

```
library(marginaleffects)

plot_predictions(
  fit, 
  newdata = datagrid(n=1, x=seq(-2, 2, 0.1), by='z'),
  by=c('x', 'z')
)
```

With `{marginaleffects}`, you can specify the value of $n$ yourself. If you don't like the aesthetics of the plot, you can use the `predictions` function to get the data that would be used to create this plot.

Comment: Thank you very much, Demetri! This is very clear! I will definitely try out the the `marginaleffects` function!